# Spring Webflux - How to convert the bellow code in a reactive friendly way?

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

```
fun getProjectOverview(fiscalYear: Int): ProjectOverview? {
        val projectList: List<Project> = projectRepo.findAllProjects(fiscalYear)
        return if (projectList.isNotEmpty()) {
            val totalProjects = projectList.size
            val completedProjects = projectList.count { it.status == "COMPLETED" } //Add enums
            val meanScheduledVariance = (projectList.sumBy { it.schedule_variance } / totalProjects)
            val meanCostVariance = (projectList.sumBy { it.cost_variance } / totalProjects)

            ProjectOverview(totalProjects, completedProjects, meanScheduledVariance, meanCostVariance)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
```

This is the business logic of my service and what I currently do in my controller is given bellow.

```
Mono.justOrEmpty(projectService.getProjectOverview(fiscalYear)).toFuture()
```

What I want to do is change my service functions to a reactive friendly way. As I am a little new to reactive programming I don't have an idea how to handle the business logic inside a Mono.

Comment: You can use `.map` for handling business logic and remapping to different output. But is your `projectRepo ` even reactive? If you are using non-reactive http/io/etc invocation, there is no benefit in doing reactive, you will only burden yourself with the difficulty of maintaining and debugging your code

Comment: @kdev I am converting the project repo to reactive at the moment. Can you give me an example how to use the map for handling business logic and remapping to different outputs. I am really lost there.

Comment: @ChathuminaVimukthi as kdev points out, you should first make sure your repo is reactive (it should not block and return a flux) otherwise "converting to reactive" probably does not mean what you think it means.